SQL query behavior based on input parameter and using one query only
Say I have a biq query table with 3 columns
customer_id, name and type.
Also, say in my query, the where clause will always have customer_id for sure. But in some cases, I want to fetch all the rows for a customer_id no matter what the type but in some cases, I want to fetch only the rows where type in (<>) is satisfied.
I can write 2 separate queries where in one of them I do have both the customer_id and type in (<>) and a second query with only customer_id.
Original ask
How do I write this in one single query say if I pass '' as type then the clause for type always evaluates to true I cannot say (and type in (<>) or true) because this will always evaluate to true. I want type to be ignored if I do not wish to filter on type
Corrected ask
How do I write this in one single query that type column is ignored in where clause at times when I want to ignore it,  or it must fetch rows along with the expected values I pass for type clause. For example in some instances I do not want type clause to impact the result of query and in another instance, I may have values v1,v2 for type and I want to fetch rows by filtering on those types as well.
The logic should be generic so that I can extend it to more columns

can you elaborate on "if I pass '' as type" do you mean to say pass inside your table? why wouldn't you then just put type condition as type in (<>, '')?

I elaborated and fixed my question. Please help now

If I understand correctly , you want to only apply type filter if a valid value for type is provided. If type is an empty string , the type condition should be ignored, but the customer_id condition should still be applied.
Let me know if the my understanding is not correct.
you can try something like this :
 SELECT customer_id, name, type
FROM your_table
WHERE customer_id = @customer_id
  AND (@type = '' OR type IN (@type));

For example :
If you pass @type = '' (empty string): The query will return all rows for customer_id = 123, regardless of the type.
SELECT customer_id, name, type
FROM customers
WHERE customer_id = 123
  AND ('' = '' OR type IN (''));  -- type filter is ignored, returns all rows for customer_id 123

If you pass @type = 'A': The query will return rows where customer_id = 123 and type is A.
SELECT customer_id, name, type
FROM customers
WHERE customer_id = 123
  AND ('A' = '' OR type IN ('A'));  -- only returns rows for customer_id 123 with type 'A'

If you pass @type = 'A', 'B': The query will return rows where customer_id = 123 and type is either A or B.
SELECT customer_id, name, type
FROM customers
WHERE customer_id = 123
  AND ('A,B' = '' OR type IN ('A', 'B'));  -- returns rows for customer_id 123 with type 'A' or 'B'


I fixed my question. Can you help now. Also, I did not know that I can do @ like that. Is this Big query regular syntax and this is not like a procedure or macro right?

Thanks, are you using Big query console or using programming APIs like python,javascript to run querires?

good question. I will use Java, but the query i want to define in a text file, Java will read that file and replace the parameters accordingly. That is prime use. Secondly if you can explain the console route also that will help but programming route is priority

Thats good if you want to use java to run the query, because it supports parameterised query with @param_name, see here in the documentation => https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#java

For console, there is no straightforward method as manual adjusting of query is still required

So your answer works still with my corrected asks right?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I was redirected to a chat room, I have responded there, can you see it? This is the chat link => https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/258844/discussion-between-samhita-and-curiousengineer
